# How to OR a raw filter with django ones

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I apologise for the title.

I need to use `to_char` (or something similar) to convert a datetime field to a string and apply an `ILIKE` on that whilst making a query.

Something like this:

```
SELECT ...

FROM mytable
WHERE 
    mytable.type = 'mytype'
 AND (
        mytable.name = 'myname' 
        OR 
        to_char(created_at, 'Mon DD, YYYY, MI:SS') ILIKE '%jun 27,%'
    )
```

As you can see, the problem is that this portion of the query has to *OR* with some filters and *AND* with others.

Considerations:

- I can't use `extra(select=...)` to convert the field to string and then filter it with `filter(..)` because django doesn't support it
- I can't use `extra(where=...)` because that would *OR* with the whole query
- I can't create an `ExtraWhere` object and *OR* (|) it with a `Q` object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find a solution.

I subclassed `django.db.models.Q` and implemented the `add_to_query(self, query, alias)` method. In this way I can *OR* and *AND* the Qs without any problems.

### Sample code:

**Please note** that this is just a simplified version and here just to give you an idea.

You should really add extra bits (e.g. support chains myobj_*my2ndobj*_my3rdobj__mydatetime_field)

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models.sql.where import ExtraWhere, OR

class DatetimeQ(Q):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DatetimeQ, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.name = kwargs.get('name')
        self.value = kwargs.get('value')

    def add_to_query(self, query, alias):
        where = ExtraWhere(["to_char(" + self.name + ", %s) ILIKE %s"], [
                'Mon DD, YYYY, MI:SS', "%%%s%%" % self.value
            ])
        query.where.add(where, OR)
```

Hope this helps.